# Throwing exceptions in a PHP Try Catch block

Tags: php, exception, try-catch, drupal-6

I have a PHP function in a Drupal 6 .module file.  I am attempting to run initial variable validations prior to executing more intensive tasks (such as database queries). In C#, I used to implement IF statements at the beginning of my Try block that threw new exceptions if a validation failed.  The thrown exception would be caught in the Catch block.  The following is my PHP code:

```
function _modulename_getData($field, $table) {
  try {
    if (empty($field)) {
      throw new Exception("The field is undefined."); 
    }
    // rest of code here...
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    throw $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

However, when I try to run the code, it's telling me that objects can only be thrown within the Catch block.

Comment: tl;dr  "throw $e->getMessage();" should be "throw $e;"

Comment: Same code seems to produce: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'throw' (T_THROW)`. I guess no longer supported.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Please note that this particular code example makes no sense, as you can simply remove the try-catch and have the same result:

```
function _modulename_getData($field, $table) {
    if (empty($field)) {
      throw new Exception("The field is undefined."); 
    }
    // rest of code here...
}
```

so Exception will be thrown and can be caught or handled elsewhere.

In case you are going to write some handling code, that may result in re-throwing the exception, you have to throw the Exception object, not a *string* returned by the getMessage() method:

```
function _modulename_getData($field, $table) {
  try {
    if (empty($field)) {
      throw new Exception("The field is undefined."); 
    }
    // rest of code here...
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    if (some condition) {
        // do some handling
    } else {
        // the error is irrecoverable
        throw $e;
    }
  }
}
```

or if you have to do some recovery, as it is often used with database transactions: do the recovery and then re-throw:

```
  catch (Exception $e) {
      $db->rollback(); // rollback the transaction
      throw $e; // let the error to be handled the usual way
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, both of your suggestions within the Catch block will resolve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 74):

To rethrow do

```
 throw $e;
```

not the message.

Comment: Thanks, this solution is most appropriate for my needs.

Comment: That's what I thought, happy to help.

Comment: Would that retain the stack information though, or would it overwrite it?

Comment: retain, to override throw a new e

Answer (score 16):

Just remove the `throw` if you are going to handle the error, or remove the try-catch block altogether, if all you need is the error message.

It's not telling you that objects can only be thrown in the catch block, it's telling you that *only objects* can be thrown, and the location of the error is in the catch block — there is a difference.

In the catch block you are trying to throw something you just caught — which in this context makes little sense anyway — and the thing you are trying to throw is a string.

A real-world analogy of what you are doing is catching a ball, then trying to throw just the manufacturer's logo somewhere else. You can only throw a whole object, not a property of the object.

Answer (score 8):

You tried to throw a `string`:

```
throw $e->getMessage();
```

You can only throw objects that implement `\Throwable`, e.g. `\Exception`.

As a sidenote: Exceptions are usually to define exceptional states of the application and not for error messages after validation. Its not an exception, when a user gives you invalid data

Comment: What would be a better way to handle validations? Would IF statements be more appropriate in handling invalid user data?

Comment: In short: Yes. In long: Treat the occurence of invalid arguments like any other situation that can occur in your app and show an other useful (error-)page. `function validateField($validate) {return empty($validate);}` and somewhere for example `if validateField($x){ echo "Field is empty";}else{doSomethingUseful();}`

Comment: @lazycommit "invalid data" is a little bit to general. If you mean "invalid values given from a user", than they are not invalid from the applications point of view, because the application _must_ expect this and therefore must treat them appropriate (--> validation). If you pass invalid data later during processing (from a backend, or because you didn't validate properly), then yes: Exception. To sum it up: Do not use `Exception`s for control flow (here: validation) :)

Comment: You can only [`throw`](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.throw.php) objects, so `throw $e;` or `throw new \Exception( $e->getMessage() );`.

Answer (score 0):

Throw needs an object instantiated by `\Exception`. Just the `$e` catched can play the trick.

```
throw $e
```