# Why is my php amazon elastic transcoder working from root but not from a browser?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I am trying to execute a job that will transcode a video file. I have a php file:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\ElasticTranscoder\ElasticTranscoderClient;

// Create a service locator using a configuration file
$client = ElasticTranscoderClient::factory(array(
        'key'    => 'my key',
        'secret' => 'my secret',
        'region' => 'us-west-2',
));

$result = $client->createJob(array(
        'PipelineId' => 'my pipeline id',
        'Input' => array(
                'Key' => 'video.mp4',
                'FrameRate' => 'auto',
                'Resolution' => 'auto',
                'AspectRatio' => 'auto', 
                'Interlaced' => 'auto',
                'Container' => 'auto',
        ),
        'Output' => array(
                'Key' => 'output.mp4',
                'ThumbnailPattern' => 'thumb{count}.jpg',
                'Rotate' => 'auto',
                'PresetId' => '1351620000001-000010',
        ),
));

?>
```

and I call this script like transcoder.php

The thing is that if I call this from my root from VPS like **php transcoder.php** it works just fine, but if I try to call it from my browser (safari, chrome, firefox) I get a

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\ElasticTranscoder\Exception\ElasticTranscoderException' in /home/my_user/public_html/test/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php:91 

Stack trace: 

#0 /home/my_user/public_html/test/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php(76): Aws\Common\Exception\NamespaceExceptionFactory->createException('Aws\ElasticTran...', Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Response), Array) 

#1 /home/my_user/public_html/test/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/ExceptionListener.php(55): Aws\Common\Exception\NamespaceExceptionFactory->fromResponse(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Response)) 

#2 [internal function]: Aws\Common\Exception\ExceptionListener->onRequestError(Object(Guzzle\Common\Event), 'request.error', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher)) 

#3 /home/my_user/public_html/test/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/Even in /home/my_user/public_html/test/transcoder.php on line 35
```

Why does it work from root and but not from browser? I need to access it from the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the settings from php.ini regarding curl and exec, that`s why you dont have permission to access the script from the browser, but works from root console.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, put a [try/catch statement](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp) around the code to see the whole error message which will help diagnose the problem.

I suspect it's because the files you are passing in `Key` do not exist as the working directory can be different if you execute on the command line vs apache.

Try specifying the full path to `video.mp4` and see if that works.

Comment: the files from Key are files from the amazon S3 bucket... not local files

Comment: ah my bad, either way use try/catch to get the full error message

Comment: I edited my post, please check it again, added the full message

Comment: thats not showing the error message from the exception thrown... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041173/throwing-exceptions-in-a-php-try-catch-block

Comment: the message is empty, only the stack can show some info... it seems that changing some settings in php.ini does the trick