# prevent error warnings if connection could not be established

Tags: php

I have some code that makes a connection to public websites and returns information about the SSL certificate - code is working perfectly fine.

I would like to add an if statement where if the connection could not be established then it would return "could not establish connection".. right now, if it cannot connect it produces a whole heap of warnings.

The code responsible for making the socket connection is as follows

MAKE SOCKET CONNECTION

```
$ctx = stream_context_create( array("ssl" => $ssloptions) );
$result = stream_socket_client("ssl://$url:443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
$cont = stream_context_get_params($result);
```

IF SOCKET CONNECTION FAILED

> echo "could not establish connection"

IF CONNECTION SUCCESSFUL

```html
foreach($cont["options"]["ssl"]["peer_certificate_chain"] as $cert) {
    openssl_x509_export($cert, $pem_encoded);
    echo $pem_encoded;
}
```

Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: you want to use try / catch : http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php |--| http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.catch.php

Comment: @MuppetGrinder, not quite sure how to apply it - thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: See [this][1] previous thred to see how to use try / catch in php


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041173/throwing-exceptions-in-a-php-try-catch-block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ctx = @stream_context_create( array("ssl" => $ssloptions) );
$result = @stream_socket_client("ssl://$url:443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

if($result == false) {
    echo "could not establish connection";
} else {
    $cont = @stream_context_get_params($result);
    foreach($cont["options"]["ssl"]["peer_certificate_chain"] as $cert) {
        openssl_x509_export($cert, $pem_encoded);
        echo $pem_encoded;
    }
}
```